# syncadapter android developers has errors parsing in eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-syncadapter

I am following android developers tutorial on syncadapters and i have the following error in the **syncadapter.xml** inside **/res/xml/**.

**[2014-05-22 15:37:07 - InSituApp] res/xml/ syncadapter.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]**

**syncadapter.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="sync.adapter.datasync"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:contentAuthority="sync.adapter.DataContentProvider"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:userVisible="false" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the `error` says, you have an invalid file name.

If you look carefully you have a space as first character. Change it to `syncadapter.xml`.